# C++ LibTorch with OpenMP - Tensor.clone() changes the max threads

Tags: c++, openmp, lib, libtorch

I am using:

- LibTorch 2.0.1
- OpenMP 201511 (4.5)

When trying to clone a `torch::Tensor` with many rows it changes the max number of threads in OMP:

```
torch::Tensor t1 = torch::empty({32950,300});
cout << "A. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
torch::Tensor t2 = t1.clone();
cout << "B. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
```

Result:

```
A. Max threads in omp: 8
B. Max threads in omp: 4
```

However, if the tensor is "small" then it does not happen:

```
torch::Tensor t1 = torch::empty({20,20});
cout << "A. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
torch::Tensor t2 = t1.clone();
cout << "B. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
```

Result:

```
A. Max threads in omp: 8
B. Max threads in omp: 8
```

Same problem happens when building a data_loader `torch::data::make_data_loader(ds, options)`

A temporary solution that worked for me:

```
int th = omp_get_max_threads();
torch::Tensor t1 = torch::empty({32950,300});
cout << "A. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
torch::Tensor t2 = t1.clone();
cout << "B. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
omp_set_num_threads(th);
cout << "C. Max threads in omp: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
```

Result:

```
A. Max threads in omp: 8
B. Max threads in omp: 4
C. Max threads in omp: 8
```

But obviously this is not a good approach. I tried to find documentation but no luck. Any suggestions?